# Entity Framework SaveChanges Optimistic Concurrency Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency

I keep getting the error Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. I understand the error but not in the context of what I am trying to do. I'll try to keep my example brief:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AccountViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var corp = dataAccess.GetCorporation(model.CorporationId);
            var prog = dataAccess.GetProgram(model.ProgramId);
            AccountModel account = dataAccess.GetAccount(model.Id);
            account.Program = prog;
            account.Corporation = corp;
            dataAccess.UpdateAccount(account);

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = account.Id });
         }
     }
```

The cshtml for those values:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProgramId, Model.Programs, "", new { @class = "span8" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationId, Model.Corporations, "", new { @class = "span8"})
```

And the viewmodel has the following values:

```
    public CorporationModel Corporation { get; set; }
    public ProgramModel Program { get; set; }
    public int? CorporationId { get; set; }
    public int? ProgramId { get; set; }
```

When the context tries to save changes, it keeps failing on Corporation, but not Program, even though they are handled the exact same way. Also, there is no concurrent change to the Corporation while the save is trying to occur.

Why is this only happening for the CorporationModel of the Account and not the ProgramModel?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens in `dataAccess.UpdateAccount(account);`?

Comment: That's a call to the class that executes the database calls. All it does is perform the update of the model to the db.

Comment: public void UpdateAccount(AccountModel account)
        {
            unitOfWork.AccountRepository.Update(account);
            unitOfWork.Save();
        }